# Can you have an sql query that compares the first result with a second condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an application that has regions, cities, teams, and users. There are 8 default user types or account types (i.e user, power user, sys admin, read only user, etc). I need to find the region that holds at least one of all of the default account types in it. All of those accounts must be from the same region. For example:

```
 SELECT users.region FROM users WHERE users.role='System Administrator' 
 OR users.role='Power User' 
 OR users.role='User' 
 OR users.role='Read Only' AND users.region = users.region;
```

Of course, this won't work. How do I make sure the query makes sure all of the user roles (account types) are from the same region?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there are eight types, then this will return regions with all eight:

```
select u.region
from users u
group by u.region
having count(distinct u.role) = 8;
```

This assumes that `u.role` has only the "default" values.  If other values can go in, then use `where`:

```
select u.region
from users u
where u.role in ('System Administrator', . . . )
group by u.region
having count(distinct u.role) = 8;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to join required number of queries

```
Select a.region from
(SELECT users.region region FROM users WHERE users.role='System Administrator') a,
(SELECT users.region region FROM users WHERE users.role='Power User') b,
(SELECT users.region region FROM users WHERE users.role='User') c,
(SELECT users.region region FROM users WHERE users.role='Read Only') d
where a.region=b.region=c.region=d.region
```